# Alias To Append New Alias to Aliases

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to duplicate all my ancient bash aliases across every option in my Windows Terminal. These are the aliases I've used for so long I type without thinking. My "nobounce" alias in powershell is kicking my tail. How do I stop the pluses but mainly the args array characters shown in output below. I'm officially googling in circles and fix one thing but break something else. I don't even know what version of attempt to display here so I'll just start with...

- PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1
- PSEdition                      Desktop
- PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
- BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1
- CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
- WSManStackVersion              3.0

**GOAL**

Create function to quickly append new one liner aliases to profile.ps1 file without the plus signs and the arg array brackets.

**FUNCTION**

```
function appender {
    if ($args[0] -ne $null) {
        Add-Content $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts+' '+$args[0]
    }
    else {
        code $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts
    }
}
```

**EXAMPLE INPUT**

```
appender "New-Alias nobounce Stop-Computer"
```

**OUTPUT / PROBLEM**

```
+ +New-Alias nobounce Stop-Computer[0]
```

Comment: I just realized how circular this is. Maybe I have larger problems than just this function.

Comment: what would `code` be in the else?

Comment: The problem with `Add-Content $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts+' '+$args[0]` is `$PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts+' '+$args[0]` is bound to the `-Path` parameter. You can simply just do `Add-Content $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts $args[0]`. The parser requires an explicit space between tokens and not an interpolated space. The first argument token binds to `-Path`. The second argument token binds to `-Value`.

Answer (score 4):

I finally understood what you are trying to do (party haha), try this, it will append code to your profile:

```
function Append-ToProfile {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [String]$arguments
    )
    if (-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($arguments)){
        Add-Content $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts -Value "`n$arguments"
    }
    else {
        code $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts
    }
}
```

Done, hope it helps.

Comment: Running `code $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts` will open the profile in VSCode

Comment: oh ok, have in mind that unless that is an alias you are not respecting the naming convention of powershell.

Comment: Not a powershell alias, just a command-line `.cmd` tool that is created when you download VSCode.

Comment: Thanks!! You saved my desktop from being tossed out of the window!! The above accomplishes exactly what I ask for. I did not explain the part about not passing arguments opens the file in VSCode. I can make that happen.

Comment: no problem, happy to help, would you mind accepting it as the answer?